# how indexer is called in Idataerrorinfo?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

In MVVM `IDataErrorInfo` is used for validation. In this on which time indexer check value can not get. and after calling it how it check value i can not get.the code is here. what is the value passed in column name.

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get { return GetValidationError(columnName); }
}
```

why use indexer for validation in wpf .can any one say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the IDataErrorInfo interface, you validate the class that implements the interface.

If you have a property Name, activate the validation and change the property, the indexer is called with string columnName  = "Name". Now you can handle the "Name" validation in an if statement

```
if(columnName  == "Name")
    // do Name validation
```

//edit

the validation is fired in wpf if you change the property by binding. You should decorate your binding like this:

```
Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Path=FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
```

Here is a nice and simple explanation of the IDataErrorInfo implementation using WPF databinding and an errortemplate.

[WPF: Validation made easy with IDataErrorInfo](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)

Comment: if i have  public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal OpeningBalance { get; set; } etc property then i can fire validation on them .

Comment: according to your xaml code  public string Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }this may be fire?????it is true?

Comment: this property is called, if an property in this class is changed by databinding.

Comment: it check nothing only return null .everything is done by indexer public string this[string columnName]
{
    get { return GetValidationError(columnName); }
}is it true?